# Calculating the minimum interval between two dates, whilst applying an extra condition

Tags: r

I have a tibble which provides information on imaging performed on different patient's eyes. The eye is represented by a `patient` and a `side` (left or right). The other variables are the `type` of image taken (colour or grayscale) and the `date` of that image. For each eye, I am trying to calculate the minimum interval in days (`minInterval`) between any grayscale and any colour image of that eye. A patient can have any count of colour and grayscale images, including 0. Where there is not at least one of each `type`, the `minInterval` is `NA`. Intervals between images of the same type are not considered.

Minimum dataset and expected output:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
  patient = c("a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"),
  side = c("right", "left", "left", "left", "left", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right"),
  type = c("colour", "colour", "grayscale", "grayscale", "colour", "colour", "grayscale", "grayscale", "colour", "grayscale", "colour"),
  date = as.Date(c("10-10-21", "10-10-21", "11-10-21", "15-04-22", "19-03-23", "20-02-20", "19-03-21", "12-03-21", "15-09-21", "10-02-20", "12-04-22"), format = "%d-%m-%y")
)

output <- tibble(
  patient = c("a", "b", "c"),
  side = c("right", "left", "right"),
  minInterval = c(NA, 1, 10)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you ?

I think i solve your questions with this dplyr functions :

```
library(dplyr)

output_ask <- data_stack %>%
  arrange(patient,side,date) %>%
  group_by(patient, side) %>%
  mutate(Gap = as.numeric(difftime(date, lag(date), units = "days"))) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Gap) | !duplicated(patient, side)) %>%  
  summarize(minInterval = min(Gap, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~na_if(., Inf))) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~na_if(., -Inf)))
```

just replace "output_ask" by your tibble name

tell me if it's ok for you !

François

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, however your solution doesn't ensure that the `minInterval` is between a grayscale and a colour image. For `patient` c the `minInterval` should be 10 as per the `output` tibble, since the 7 day interval is between two grayscale images.

Comment: oh i'm sorry i made a mistake if you want you just have to create another lag function to check if the precedent test is the same or not then you filter the minimum statement in dplyr

Comment: @francoisLENNE Feel free to edit your original answer if OP provides further clarification. Just make it clear you've added a new section as an edit

Comment: @Quinton.Quagliano hello i will try to  find some bandwith this weekend in order to finish that ;)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to create separate tibbles for grayscale and colour images, and then join them together using `left_join` which creates a row for every combination of grayscale and colour image. Then I used `group_by` and `filter` to find the minimum interval. This solution doesn't show the NA values I had originally planned for (just excludes them from the result), but I didn't actually need this so I just stopped there.

```
colour_images <- data %>% 
  filter(type == 'colour') %>% 
  select(patient, side, colourDate = date)

grayscale_images <- data %>% 
  filter(type == 'grayscale') %>% 
  select(patient, side, grayscaleDate = date)

output <- colour_images %>% 
  left_join(grayscale_images, relationship = 'many-to-many') %>% 
  mutate(minInterval = abs(colourDate - grayscaleDate)) %>% 
  group_by(patient, side) %>% 
  filter(minInterval == min(minInterval)) %>% 
  select(patient, side, minInterval)
```